# In Gravity forms, form is disappeared after successfully submitting the form

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

By using gravity form I have generated a contact form. When I submit the form, the form disappears and a success message is shown.

What I want, is that the form stays, and a success message is shown below the form. Can anyone help me solve this..

Answer (score 2):

You can use this filter

```
add_filter('gform_get_form_filter', function($form_string, $form) {

  $form_string = str_replace( "replaceWith", "append", $form_string );

  return $form_string;
}, 10, 2);
```

**$form_string** contains javascript which is executed after form submit.

You're replacing the javascript function **replaceWith** with **append**.

Works perfect for me.

Comment: Thanks for this, it does the job although the ajax spinner is still visible which may confuse the users

Answer (score 0):

**Enable AJAX**

Checking this option will enable your form to be submitted via AJAX. Submitting the form via AJAX allows the form to be submitted without requiring a page refresh.

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/embedding-a-form/

You can enable it in the settings if you go into Wordpress admin -> form -> settings

Comment: The form still disappears when it's submitted via AJAX.  There is a hook in this thread which certainly used to work, not sure if it still does - https://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/display-form-after-submission

Answer (score 0):

This answer responds to [Adrian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237822/in-gravity-forms-form-is-disappeared-after-successfully-submitting-the-form#comment109554645_60756158) on [Svetlozar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756158/14809797).

To disable the Ajax realoader thing just go to posts, find the form from there and you can disable it in the settings on the right side in advanced options.

Alternatively I am thinking just find the CSS for that reloader and use display:none in CSS.

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! Things work differently here. As Tyler2P and lissettdm said, we separate answers from comments. Your answer is great, but it also contained a comment which references another answer. Anyone is allowed to submit a question or answer, but we want to make sure that bots and trolls can't post comments or votes until we know they mean well to the community. That's why we ask that you submit questions and answer others' questions first, like the second half of your answer here  Best of luck and have fun!